# No matching function in multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, delegating-constructor

I'm new to inheritance in C++ and decided to try some experiments to learn about this subject.

The code below shows the hierarchy of classes I'm creating:

classes.h

```
class base
{
protected:
    int _a;
    int _b;
    int _c;;
    base(int b, int c);
};

class sub_one : public virtual base
{
public:
    sub_one(int a, int b) : base(a, b)
    {
        // do some other things here
    }

    // other members
};


class sub_two : public virtual base
{
protected:
    int _d;
public:
    sub_two(int a, int b, int c = 0) : base(a, b) 
    {
        // do something
    }

    // other members
};


class sub_three : public sub_one, public sub_two
{
private:
    bool flag;
public:
    sub_three(int a, int b, int c = 0) : base(a, b) 
    {
        // do something    
    }
};
```

classes.c

```
base::base(int a, int b)
{
    // ...
}
```

The compiler shows me the messages:

> no matching function for call to sub_one::sub_one()
>
> no matching function for call to sub_one::sub_one()
>
> no matching function for call to sub_two::sub_two()
>
> no matching function for call to sub_two::sub_two()

I just can't find out what is wrong.

Comment: `sub_three` constructor initializes `base`, but forgets to initialize the other two of its base classes. Neither of `sub_one` and `sub_two` have default constructors, so you need to explicitly list them in `sub_three`'s constructor initializer list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sub_three(int a, int b, int c = 0) : base(a, b) 
{
    // do something    
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
sub_three(int a, int b, int c = 0) : base(a, b), sub_one(), sub_two() 
{
    // do something    
}
```

Since there are no such constructors in `sub_one` and `sub_two`, the compiler reports the errors. You can add default constructors to `sub_one` and `sub_two` to remove the errors.

Answer (score 1):

`sub_three` constructor initializes `base`, and call the default constructor of `sub_one` and `sub_two` which doesn't exist, you may need

```
class sub_three : public sub_one, public sub_two
{
private:
    bool flag;
public:
    sub_three(int a, int b, int c = 0)
       : base(a, b), sub_one(a,b), sub_two(a,b,c), flag(false)
    {
        // do something    
    }
};
```